# What is Salesforce?

Tags: help

Because of things I do at work, I have become aware of Salesforce. So I decided to join this site to learn about it.

I searched on my favourite search engine with the phrase "what is salesforce" and it came up with a few sponsored links.

I was hoping to find something along the lines of "sales force is...", please explain, what salesforce is? I can tell that it is something quite complicated and that there are people that know about it, but I have not had any direct contact with it and I would like to know.

I am computer literate as it were, and I can write source code, but my eyes glaze over when people say things like "erp" or "crm". So far I think that salesforce is a crm, this is something that I have gathered from face to face conversations, and I think that a crm is something that a business will use to keep track communications between it and it's clients, is that what salesforce is? Though I must say, I barely grasp what a crm actually is. Please explain what salesforce is, what it is used for, who uses it.

I understand that this question might have a massive answer that takes hundreds of pages of printed material to answer, but that is not what I am after.

Comment: Welcome to the site alex. Could yo be more specific ? We can understand that you're new to salesforce,  but the question is as vague as asking what/who microsoft or google are. They are much more than the producers of the OS or the search engine.  The stackexchange site is focused on specific questions, this is quite broad. It may be good to have a look at our [welcome tour](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help)

Answer (score 7):

Here is the way I describe it to my engineering team:

> Salesforce is a relational database with a fancy UI that allows those
>   not technically inclined to create tables, fields, and records in such
>   database. As part of the fancy UI, Salesforce has built default tables
>   to support functions that exist across a variety of businesses, like
>   customer accounts, individual contacts, and sales opportunities. You can also use the fancy UI to create your own tables (which are known as custom objects in Salesforce vernacular) that are needed specifically for your business. The
>   default "CRM" system comes with a standard set of tables and UI to
>   modify table structure, view and add records in those tables, and run
>   reports. In addition to all of this, Salesforce has products that it
>   owns (like Pardot or ExactTarget) which you can add-on to your
>   Salesforce instance that provides additional functionality (like
>   marketing automation). You can also use the Salesforce AppExchange to
>   get add-ons that third parties have created to bring additional
>   functionality to Salesforce.

As a technology person, I had the same problem getting started with Salesforce. The company is outstanding at marketing, but for a technical person it's easy to roll your eyes at all the marketing speak. It's only when I got into it myself that I realized it's just a well-thought-out database with an easily customizable UI and platform, a plethora of supporting applications, and a strong community. The confluence of these factors makes Salesforce powerful.

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce is an cloud application platform sold as a subscription.

On the platform, users can build the tables, fields, forms, UI, mobile apps, public sites, customer and partner communities, reporting, automation, APIs, identity, security, collaboration, marketing automation, etc that they need using either code or point and click tooling.  The core idea of the platform is to give you the 80% of every app that's the same, so you can focus on the 20% that's unique to your business or organization.

On top of this platform, Salesforce offers bundles of things that serve a particular market segment.  CRM for sales teams was first, is the most famous and is the most commercially successful so far.  It's infinitely customizable because of the platform underneath it, but it comes "out of the box" with most things a sales team needs already configured.

Third party software companies have built apps for HR, finance, logistics, gamification, mapping, document management, e-commerce, and thousands more.  You can install these from the AppExchange instead of making them yourself.

Customers have built tons more apps for their own use that we'll never see unless you go work there.